# Break a string in 3 parts in perl

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I have the following string:

```
my $string = "<b>My Name: John Smith < /br> </br>Rest of a big text bla bla bla …";
```

I want to break it into 3 strings.
One having "My Name:"
One having "John Smith"
And one having the rest of the text i.e. Rest of a big text bla bla bla
The problem is that "John Smith" is a variant. I.e. could be any name and I want to extract that.
I have tried something like:
`my @vals = split (/(<b>My Name: John Smith :*+<br >)/, $string);` 
But this does not even compile.
How do I do this in Perl?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/perl for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Perl modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: For a limited use like this, regex is fine, and in fact more or less necessary to do things an HTML parser can't/won't do (such as pull out the text after "My Name" within the same tag). This isn't actually parsing HTML, just pattern matching text that happens to be within HTML.

Comment: @AndyLester:I am not parsing a page. I need only this string.It is not a full page otherwise I would do as you said

Comment: Are those really *`</br>`* or *`<br/>`*?

Comment: `split` requires that you identify what separates the strings you want returned, but that's very hard to identify in your situation, and you'd still need some pre- or post-processing to remove the leading and trailing text. `split` is not the right choice.

Comment: To explain what @Sinan Ünür's comment, it should be `<br>` in HTML and either `<br></br>` or `<br/>` in XHTML. `</br>` alone is not valid in either.

Comment: @Jim: HTML is HTML, whether it's one string or it's an entire page.  If that input can change its format, then you're going to have problems in the future if you go with regexes.

Answer (score 3):

A simple regular expression should work.

```
my ($label, $name, $rest) = $string =~ m=<b>(.*?): (.*?) < /br> </br>(.*)=;
print "$label\n$name\n$rest\n";
```

Note that the space between `<` and `/` is not the correct syntax in HTML and might not be rendered as you hope.

BTW, have you noticed the string contains the character U+2026?

Comment: No. How did you notice that?

Comment: @Jim: I pasted the string into my editor (emacs) and it told me it cannot save it in plain ASCII.

Comment: Just for reference, U+2026 is `…`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $html = q{<b>My Name: John Smith <br /> <br />Rest of a big text bla bla bla …};

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(string => $html);

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('b')) {
    my $text = $parser->get_text('br');
    next unless my ($label, $name) = ($text =~ m{\A (My Name:) \s+ (.+) }xs);
    $name =~ s{\s+\z}{};
    $text = $parser->get_text('/b');
    $text =~ s{\A\s+}{};
    $text =~ s{\s+\z}{};
    say "|$_|" for $label, $name, $text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $string = "<b>My Name: John Smith < /br> </br>Rest of a big text bla bla bla …";

my @vals = 
  map { /(My Name:)\s*(.+)/ ? ($1,$2) : $_ } 
  grep length,
  split /\s* <.+?> \s*/x, $string;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@vals;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'My Name:',
          'John Smith',
          'Rest of a big text bla bla bla .'
        ];
```

Comment: What if `<b>` was missing?

Comment: @Jim good point; btw on which parts of string you can rely on?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions and the predefined variable " **$'** " which refers to the the part of the string after the part that has matched the regular expression!